# Вылезает ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax, когда использую метод send_message

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Я учусь писать телеграмм бота и хочу, чтобы через код бот отправлял сообщения, 
но у меня вылезает ошибка SyntaxError. Ломаю голову в чем проблема, перерыл различные источники, но решение так и не нашёл.

Файл number - это отдельный файл, где лежит токен бота

```
import telebot
import number

bot = telebot.TeleBot(number.token)
bot.send_message(111111111, "Yahoo")
```

И в итоге результат такой:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ринат/PycharmProjects/telegram_bot/The bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import telebot
  File "C:\Users\ринат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 463
    def async():
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: у вас ошибка уже при импорте модуля телебот, до send_message дело даже не доходит.

Comment: Если не затруднит, то как правильно мне нужно импортировать модуль

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с Python 3.7 `async` является ключевым словом и не может быть использовано в качестве названия функции. Попробуйте обновить telebot, проблема [была исправлена год назад](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/pull/526).

Comment: У меня самая последняя версия телебота

Comment: В таком случае вы нашли баг и вам надо создать issue в его репозитории.

Comment: @Amir или у вас другой модуль, который называется тоже телебот, или не последняя версия. В последней версии строка 463 в файле инициализации совсем не такая, как в тексте вашей ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, как вы устанавливали библиотеку telebot если `pip install PyTelegramBotAPI` то правильно

Потом для отправки сообщения пользователю нужно получить его message.chat.id , а для этого уже нужно создавать функцию при которой бот будет ждать опрделенной команды и только после ее отправления он будет уже слать сообщения

### ПРИМЕР

```
import telebot;
bot = telebot.TeleBot('%ваш токен%');

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start_help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: У автора вопроса скрипт валится сразу после `import telebot` из-за ошибки в библиотеке.

Comment: я в начале ответа написал что нужно устанавливать PyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: Он у него установлен.

Comment: У него не та библиотека, на этой строке нет `def async()`

Answer (score 0):

нужно изменить все упоминания asynce в файле **init**.py на asynce_dec

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, где вы заметили упоминание о  `asynce` в вопросе?

Comment: \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py, поэтому пути открываете файл и начиная с 463 строчки меняете  asynce на asynce_dec. p.s что бы открыть папку appdata надо вызвать диалог win+r и ввести в поиск %appdata%

Comment: А вы пробовали? Что у вас в строчке 463, можете скопировать сюда?
И вся доп. информация должна быть в сообщении, не в комментарии, для этого есть кнопка [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1103825/edit).